# Confidence Interval/Margin of Recall or Precision

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, confusion-matrix, precision-recall

If I have a confusion matrix that is based upon a sample set, how do I determine the statistical power (confidence margin/interval) of my recall/precision/etc metrics? I know how to do statistical power analysis for the probability of conversion itself but how do I do it for the recall/precision?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer to this. It is a slightly modified equation of standard confidence interval calculation of p +/- Z_score_at_alpha * std_error. The only difference is that p (basically your recall probability) is computed with an offset -> adjusted_recall=(TP+2)/(TP+FN+4).

The general idea is that the standard confidence interval equation doesnt work when p is at 0 or 1. This equation provides an adjustment that allows it to work. its just a fudge factor.

Also, the std error is now sqrt(adjusted_recall(1-adjusted_recall)/(N+4)).
This is known as the wilson score interval - 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval

http://www.stat.ucdavis.edu/~kwwong/STA13-SS1-12/Statistics_13_files/lecture05.pdf

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109429/wilsons-adjustment-for-sample-proportion

Comment: You must mean `TP+2` in the adjusted recall to be in brackets for the whole calculation to be between 0 and 1. Additionally, I'm a bit confused about the formula. The Wilson interval provided does not have the same appearance. Have I missed something?

Comment: Here's my question about the topic: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/363382/confidence-interval-of-precision-recall-and-f1-score

Comment: @Felix Thanks for your question. yes, there is a bracket on the numerator (TP + 2). The wilson adjustment is explained here - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109429/wilsons-adjustment-for-sample-proportion . Its just a way to get confidence intervals for proportions which is what precision and recall is.